# Laravel validation errors not showing, while they do show in the 422 error

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-blade, rules

I have a simple webinterface where I am able to select a certain market, price, targets and stoploss for a personal cryptocurrency trade on an exchange.

I have added some default laravel validation rules, some of them show up on the webinterface like they should, but one of them in particular is not while it does trigger because when I inspect the `422` `POST` error, it does show up in the response.

Here the form is showing errors, except on the stoploss part, but the stoploss error is not showing up on the webinterface:

[image]

I have simplified the rule to only have "require" for testing purposes, also with more rules it does not work. the rules:

```
'market' => 'required',
'trade_value' => 'required|numeric|min:10',
'limit-price' => 'sometimes|min:1|numeric',
'stop-price' => 'required',
```

the return response from the 422 POST (laravel creates this?):

```
{
    "message":"The given data was invalid",
    "errors":{
    "market":[
        "The market field is required."
    ],
    "limit-price":[
        "The limit-price must be at least 1.",
        "The limit-price must be a number."
    ],
    **"stop-price":[
        "The stop-price field is required."
    ]**
}
```

form code per request (I removed some div's that are not involved in the subject):

````
<form method="POST" action="/trades" accept-charset="UTF-8" novalidate="" class="ajax-form"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="sdgsdge563456">
           <!-- Default box -->
<div class="card ">
    <div class="card-header with-border" style="display:none;">
        <div class="float-left">

        </div>
        <div class="card-tools float-right">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
               <div class="col-12">
                   <div class="form-group   required-field "><label for="market">Market</label><select class="form-control " id="market" name="market"><option selected="selected" value="">Select Market ...</option><option value="btc-perpetual">BTC-PERPETUAL</option><option value="eth-perpetual">ETH-PERPETUAL</option></select></div>
               </div>
           </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="card-footer" style="display:none;">

    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer-->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
           <!-- Default box -->
<div class="card ">
    <div class="card-header with-border" style="display:none;">
        <div class="float-left">

        </div>
        <div class="card-tools float-right">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
               <div class="col-12">
                   <div class="form-group   required-field "><label for="trade_value">Trade Value</label><div class="input-group "><input class="form-control " placeholder="Trade Value" id="trade_value" name="trade_value" type="number" value="10"><div class="input-group-addon  input-group-append"><div class="input-group-text">USD</div></div></div></div>
               </div>
           </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="card-footer" style="display:none;">

    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer-->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
           <!-- Default box -->

<!-- /.box -->
           <!-- Default box -->
<div class="card ">
    <div class="card-header with-border" style="display:none;">
        <div class="float-left">

        </div>
        <div class="card-tools float-right">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">

           <div class="entrytype entrylimit">
               <div class="row">
                   <div class="col-12">
                       <div class="form-group   required-field "><label for="limit-price">Price</label><div class="input-group "><input class="form-control " placeholder="Price" id="limit-price" name="limit-price" type="number"><div class="input-group-addon  input-group-append"><div class="input-group-text">USD</div></div></div></div>
                   </div>
               </div>

           </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->
    <div class="card-footer" style="display:none;">

    </div>
    <!-- /.box-footer-->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
        </form>```
````

Comment: Is this in a request class or a controller?

Comment: I guess you're expecting to see the trade_value validation error, confirm that the name of the input field is the same as trade_value in your validation array

Comment: add your form code in the question.

Comment: to Evan:
Its a seperate class extending BaseRequest, the rules are in public function rules()

to codervine:
trade_value corresponds with the html id/name of the input field.


to zahid:
should be in there now

Comment: It looks like I found something.

So basically the website consist of a row, and inside this row 3 times a div that together make 3 divs next to eachother.

```<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
  </div>
</div>```

It looks like everything inside the first of the 3 divs is validated, everything after that is not validated, it stops after the first..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue myself.

Basically the form start code should be in front of the 3 column divs, otherwise laravel would stop validation after the first div.

Comment: Write in the comments instead of an answer please